# The use of modules in control theory

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, modules

So far I have seen the use of vector spaces in control theory and other notions from linear algebra; So I wonder if there's a use of this abstraction of modules over rings in control theory? any literature you can suggest?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Modules theory over the rings of principal ideals is the main tool of control theory.
Linear control theory mainly deals with matrices whose entries are polynomials.
Polynomials is the ring of principal ideals. Matrices over this ring require modules theory.
This fact is usually hidden in the books of control theory written for engineers,
because modules (unfortunately) are not a part of the standard engineering math curriculum.

These textbooks (on my opinion) only obscure the matter.

Answer (score 2):

I might find an answer to my question, in the two volumes of Pommerat, here:
https://books.google.co.il/books?id=F13-yWtv4fIC&pg=PA50&lpg=PA50&dq=using+modules+in+control+theory&source=bl&ots=-Xnzagrnuq&sig=Tuyfe9jfnksw2tXig0kCUrdkqcw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CC0Q6AEwA2oVChMIzP2NzpfxxwIVQdIaCh0usw-p#v=onepage&q=using%20modules%20in%20control%20theory&f=false

It seems differential modules have some application to control theory.

If you have further suggestions do tell.